# Can't send big json (with byte array inside) to server using xamarin ios single view application

Tags: ios, json, xamarin, bigdata

### I can't send a lot of data (json with byte array inside) from xamarin ios single view app to server ASP .NET.

My models (same on ios app and server)

```
public class VirtualTourDataModel
{
    public string VTName { get; set; }
    public List<ViewPoint> ViewPoints { get; set; }
}

public class ViewPoint
{
    public string PointName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Video { get; set; }
    public List<bool> Connections { get; set; }
}
```

---

how i set bytearray:

```
ViewPoint viewPoint = new ViewPoint();
                viewPoint.Video = ToByteArray(NSData.FromUrl(outputFileUrl));
                VirtualTourData.ViewPoints.Add(viewPoint);


        public static byte[] ToByteArray(NSData data)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[data.Length];
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data.Bytes, bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(data.Length));
            return bytes;
        }
```

---

How do i send data:

```
VirtualTourDataModel vtModel = new VirtualTourDataModel();
            vtModel.VTName = VirtualTourData.VTName;
            vtModel.ViewPoints = VirtualTourData.ViewPoints;               
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vtModel);

            string sUrl = "http://192.168.0.56:6240/api/UploadVT/Upload";

    try
            {
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.0.56:6240");


                    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    var url = new Uri(string.Concat("http://192.168.0.56:6240", "/api/UploadVT/Upload"));
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // this result string should be something like: "{"token":"rgh2ghgdsfds"}"
                        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }                        
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
```

---

I receive this error in catch:

{System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.EndWrite (System.IAsyncResult r) [0x000b9] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs:617 
  at System.IO.Stream+<>c.b__53_1 (System.IO.Stream stream, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs:729 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1+FromAsyncTrimPromise`1[TResult,TInstance].Complete (TInstance thisRef, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] endMethod, System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:1441 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:447 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__63.MoveNext () [0x00324] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:379 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+d__48.MoveNext () [0x00080] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
  at EasyVTApp.VTLinkViewController+d__2.MoveNext () [0x00107] in D:\magistr\EasyVTApp\EasyVTApp\VTLinkViewController.cs:79 }

Comment: BY the way, my controller method: 
[HttpPost] public string Upload(VirtualTourDataModel data) {....}

Comment: `lot of data` / 'big'  What is the size?

Comment: size of video is about 100Mb